# Don't set a cookie or show in browser history

Tags: wordpress, cookies, browser-history

I am currently working on a website for a non-profit organization for abused women. The organization would like the website visitor to not have a cookie set, and do not want their website to be recorded in the person's browser history (is this even possible).

Does anybody know how I can tell WordPress not to set a cookie for any visitor unless signing into the admin section?

Comment: It's not possible for a website to remove itself from a browser's history - the user has to consciously choose an anonymous browsing mode for this to happen (e.g. Chrome's Incognito mode).

Comment: To remove cookies for a site, it seems you can do it via htaccess (though of course do test any solution you implement): http://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2012/05/disable-cookies-using-htaccess/